# Gmond problem in ganglia

Tags: ganglia

I have ganglia installed on my server, it's been running good, so I tried to add some perl scripts using Gmetric and cron, at first it was running good, but after I made some changes to the script (by changing the name of the metric and some values), old values of the metric are still showing and Gmond retrieving data anymore, I think that Gmond's is keeping a copy of the perl file, because even after I deleted it graph are still showing and no metric is working.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ganglia uses [`RRDTool`](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/index.en.html) as it's back end database.  I provided the link to RRDTool so that you can understand how to interact with the database.

The short answer is that you cannot simply modify the perl scripts that are gathering metrics for you and change the name of the metric, or add/delete metrics, and have those changes automatically propagate into RRDTool.  You need to [read and understand](https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/wiki/Ganglia-Documents) how Ganglia actually works under the covers to know exactly how to create new metrics, and have your modified scripts add them properly.

The minimum set of steps required would be something like:

- create a new RRD database to store the metric
- add the metric to the web front end for display
- add the metric to a collection tool (your perl script, or a python script, or a shell script, etc, etc)

If you google for ["Ganglia RRDTool Tutorial"](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ganglia+rrdtool+tutorial) you will find a number of resources that can help you gain experience with how the pieces all fit together, and how you can customize them to fit your specific requirements.